# how to use custom css file in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, custom-masterpage

I am extremely new to Sharepoint and have started exploring sharepoint 2013.

I have downloaded copy of seattle.master and created my own master page called `MyFirstMaster.master`.

Then created new empty sharepoint solution in visual studio 2012 added my master page. Then deployed solution. So far so good.

Now i want to have my own css file so searched in master file and found that it is using this

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/oslo.css" runat="server" EnableCssTheming="true" />
```

So i added one more line below which can use my custom css

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/MyCustom.css" runat="server" EnableCssTheming="true" />
```

I also included `MyCustom.css` file in below path same as it was for `oslo.css`

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES
```

Then i deployed solution but still its not using my css file. I dont have sharepoint designer. How can i use my own css file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preferred way now to reference styles in SharePoint 2013 is to upload them to the master page gallery, you can create a folder in your master page gallery and upload your CSS file there either manually or using a module in Visual Studio. Once you do so, you can refernce it using :

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/YourSiteFolder/YourCSSFile.css %&gt;"
      runat="server"
      after="corev15.css"/>
```

Note that using SPUrl token doesn't work with SharePoint foundation.

Comment: In which path i should create "YourSiteFolder"

Comment: Inside the master page gallery itself.

Comment: can you give me real path

Comment: Create a folder in your master page gallery called for example: MyMasterStyles, and add your style sheet file to it, so the path will be: SPUrl: ~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyMasterStyles/MyCSSFile.css

Comment: Thank you that worked but still not able to understand where is path on my drive of that master page gallery

Comment: The master page gallery is not on your drive, it's on SharePoint in your site collection which is stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of manners to do this, but this is how I'll do it:

1) Create a module in VS

2) add a CSS file in the module

3) Reference the CSS file in my master page, for exemple :

`<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" name="<% $SPUrl:~site/SiteAssets/css/Style.css%>"/>`)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from my own custom masterpage:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_layouts/15/<<custom solution name>>/Styles/custom.css %>"
```

where the file is deployed by a feature to hive at 15/my solution folder/Styles/custom.css. You can manually place the file there as well to check.