# Add a top banner on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, branding

I have researched from google as well as articles from this site but with no help regarding adding a banner on SharePoint 2013. This was easy on 2010 version but 2013 is giving me trouble.

This is what I have done so far:

On Master page: seattle.html I have linked my css file under the themable link.
and on my CSS file, I added the following code:

```
#s4-titlerow {
    background:#F9F9F9 url('/SiteAssets/banner.jpg') repeat-x 0px 0px;
    margin:0;
    min-height:121px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding:30px 0 0 310px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

but the banner is not showing when I load the page.

Answer (score 1):

Your styles appear to be fine, so I would say you have a problem with the CSS file reference.

you can use [CSS Registration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134991/how-to-use-custom-css-file-in-sharepoint-2013)

```
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration ID="CSSReg5" name="<%$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/CSS/styles.css%>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

or use [AlternateCSSURl](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148029/add-css-to-masterpage-sharepoint-online-office-365)

> 1. Find "Site Collection Features" setting and enable all features with name "publishing" in it.
> 2. Find "Manage Site Features" setting and enable all feature with name "publishing" in it.
> 3. Find "Master Page" setting link under "Look and Feel".
> 4. Click "Alternate CSS URL". This is where you apply your own CSS file.
> 5. Upload a CSS file to any document library. Ideally to "Style Library".
> 6. Go to step 4 and choose your uploaded CSS file.

or [html reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9bc131c3-db38-46b2-992a-abdcf2dac9b0/external-css-file-in-html-master-page?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/test/style.css %&gt;" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile" />-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the full URL for the background image.

```
#s4-titlerow {
    background:#F9F9F9 url('http://example/sites/company/SiteAssets/banner.jpg') repeat-x 0px 0px;
    margin:0;
    min-height:121px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding:30px 0 0 310px;
    word-wrap:break-word; }
```